# Why is $\sup\limits_{R>0}\int\lvert K(x)\rvert dx\le 2\sup\limits_{R>0}\frac{1}{R}\int\lvert K(x)\rvert\lvert x\rvert dx$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

[image]

> If I show that  $$\frac 12\sup\limits_{R>0}\int\limits_{R\le|x|\le 2R}\lvert K(x)\rvert dx\le \sup\limits_{R>0}\frac 1R\int\limits_{|x|\le R}\lvert K(x)\rvert |x| dx\le 2\sup\limits_{R>0}\int\limits_{R\le|x|\le 2R}\lvert K(x)\rvert dx$$, where $K$ is defined as $K(x)=\frac{\Omega\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right)}{\lvert x \rvert ^n}$ and $\Omega\in L^1(\mathbb S^{n-1})$, then I show the equivalence between $(5.3.4)$ and $(5.3.6)$ (this is actually an exercise in the book of Loukas Grafakos, Classical Fourier Analysis $3$rd ed.)

$\Omega$ is not explicitly defined, it's just radial function, If I write it in spherical coordinates, I still cannot conclude anything, I think there's another property of $K$ needed.

$\int_{B_{2R}\setminus B_R} K(|x|) dx = \int_R^{2R} K(r) r^{n-1} dr \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} d\Omega.$

Another Question: Is the LHS equivalent to

$\sup\limits_{R/2>0}\int\limits_{R/2\le|x|\le R}\lvert K(x)\rvert dx$

or to

$\sup\limits_{\epsilon>0}\int\limits_{\epsilon\le|x|\le R}\lvert K(x)\rvert dx$

(Is the ratio or the difference relevant here ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$\sup \limits_{R > 0} \int_{R \le |x| \le 2R} |K(x)| \, dx = \sup \limits_{S > 0} \int_{S/2 \le |x| \le S} |K(x)| \, dx$$

holds, as the change of variable $R = S/2$ shows.

Let $M_n = \{x \mid 2^{-(n + 1)} R \le |x| \le 2^{-n} R\}$. Then by monotone convergence we have:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{R} \int\limits_{|x| \le R} |K(x)| |x| \, dx &= \frac{1}{R} \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty \int_{M_n} |K(x)| |x| \, dx \le \frac{1}{R} \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty \int_{M_n} |K(x)| 2^{-n} R\, dx \\
&\le \frac{1}{R} \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty A_1 2^{-n} R = 2A_1
\end{align*}$$

The other inequality is easier to see:
$$\frac{1}{2} \int \limits_{R/2 \le |x| \le R} |K(x)| \, dx \le \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{R/2 \le |x| \le R} |K(x)| \frac{|x|}{R/2} \le \frac{1}{R} \int \limits_{|x| \le R} |K(x)| |x|\, dx$$

Comment: Great thanks a lot. No property of $K$ is needed. In the $2$nd line can you also write by change of variables $\sup\limits_{\epsilon>0}\int\limits_{\epsilon\le|x|\le R}$ |K(x)| dx ? (not useful for the proof but out of curiosity)

Comment: You can't, see for example $K(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. While $\int_ {R/2}^R |K(x)| = \ln(2)$ is constant, the value of $\int_\varepsilon^R |K(x)|$ goes to infinity for fixed $R$ and $\varepsilon \searrow 0$.